# Array of JSON in Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I want to use individual values coming as a array in JSON payload. Please suggest the approach to do it.

***Request Payload:***

```
{ 
  "ID": "123456" 
  "Date": “18-02-2019"
  "ReportLocation" : ["obj1", "obj2", "obj3"…]
 }
```

I want to pass these values (obj1, obj2, obj3...) to subsequent NIFI processor as an attribute.

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54720905/array-of-json-to-mupliple-json-object-in-nifi

Answer (score 0):

[SplitJson](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitJson/index.html) splits a JSON File into multiple, separate FlowFiles for an array element specified by a JsonPath expression.

So this looks like a quick JSON transformation from the payload single object to `ReportLocation` list items strings objects, The JsonPath Expression you will need is: `$.ReportLocation`, in your example, 1 request will be in and 3 flow files will be out with the values of each `$.ReportLocation[]`.

Comment: these values will be coming as dynamic.. so for now I have given it as 3 values.But it could be more than that or less than that.

Comment: It will be dynamic, the number of output flowfiles will be equal to the length of the array so it'll be fine.